# Build directed graph on windows forms with data from DB

Tags: c#, winforms, dgml, graphx-net

I have an objects with data, and each object connected to other objects.
(Like object1->object2, object2->object3, object1->object3).
For example objects and connections represented by two classes:

```
class Object
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public Object(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}

class Relation
{
    public Object obj1{get;set;}
    public Object obj2{get;set;}
    public Relation(Object o1, Object o2)
    {
        obj1 = o1;
        obj2 = o2;
    }
}
```

And, for example, data stored this way:

```
List<Relation> relations = new List<Relation>();
List<Object> objects = new List<Object>();
```

I generated a [DGML (Directed Graph Markup Language)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn966108.aspx) file in my solution, which contains info for a Visual Studio DGML Viewer to build a graph
I need to show its content to user through the form. I am using Windows Forms for my project. But there are no such control as VS DGML Viewer.
So I need another idea how to build directed graph automatically, because I cannot sort data to get correct looking graph made with System.Graphics.
How can I achieve the goal?

**Solution**

I used a [GraphX for .NET library](https://github.com/panthernet/GraphX) to achieve my goal. This library allows to build different graphs based on data with automated visualization. But for windows forms needed to use `ElementHost` control to host WPF controls inside windows form.

For building graph I used this code:

```
private GraphExample GenerateGraph()
        {
            var dataGraph = new GraphExample();

            foreach (Object obj in objects)
            {
                var dataVertex = new DataVertex(obj.name);
                dataGraph.AddVertex(dataVertex);
            }

            var vlist = dataGraph.Vertices.ToList();

            foreach (Relation rel in relations)
            {
                var v1 = vlist.First(x => x.Text == rel.obj1.name);
                var v2 = vlist.First(x => x.Text == rel.obj2.name);
                var dataEdge = new DataEdge(v1, v2) { Text = $"From {v1.Text} to {v2.Text}" };
                dataGraph.AddEdge(dataEdge);
            }

            return dataGraph;
        }
```

Comment: What is DGML file? How does it look like?

Comment: it look like directed graph with nodes connected by links, created using sml with "http://schemas.microsoft.com/vs/2009/dgml" scheme. Something like this: http://www.softwareprocessengineering.com/_SPDiag/DGMLNOGroups.jpg

Comment: Possible related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206450/is-there-a-dgml-viewer

Comment: Maybe I can convert dgml to image using code somehow?  Or maybe there are some alternatives for automatic visual graph generation?